# How to store functions return value inside other function

Tags: python, html, flask

I have two functions in flask
I am not really sure if this is good approach or not ?
First one is template renderer

```
@app.route('/displayreports')
def display_report():
   
    return render_template('Displayreports.html', reports=reports)
```

Second one is api function to update the data called from html by button. I want to store function_last_used_date value in server side to show it later at display report. Is there anyway to store it outside a function without calling it ?

```
@app.route('/displayreports/data')
def api_get_reports():
    import datetime

    function_last_used_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    get_reports()
    
    return {'reports': list(reports), 'last_updated_date': updated_date}
```

Comment: "Is there anyway to store it outside a function without calling it" - no

Comment: Did my answer help, or any problems?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to store the variable `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

- using Session data (see https://pythonbasics.org/flask-sessions/)

> Flask Session saves data specific to a browser session initiated by a user and eliminates the need for global variables.

- or in a simple database.